# How to hang wall cabinets with the upper plaster removed

Tags: drywall, walls, kitchens, cabinets

I am trying to hang wall cabinets obviously want them level and plumb.

However, when I removed my old cabinets half of the wall’s plaster is missing.

[image]

This creates an extremely unlevel surface.

My thoughts were to drywall and try to match the thickness of the plaster there

Or

To screw in drywall shims and make the studs level as best as possible.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you mind adding a longer-view picture, and perhaps one at an angle so we can better see the depth differences? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you'd need to completely finish the wall in  order to proceed, but I'd at least cut the plaster cleanly (and the vacuum well) to stifle the endless stream of dust that's likely to fall out from behind the cabinetry.

Answer (score 2):

I'd presume that by "drywall shims" you mean pieces of drywall to bring the surface out to the level of the plaster. In that case, your two options are essentially the same thing, and, I think, a great idea.

I'd suggest, though, that before you start down that path, you measure the thickness of the plaster & lath from the stud face. You *may* be better off using strips of plywood/OSB that are a very close equivalent to the thickness of what you've got there. There is a lot more variety in plywood/OSB than there are in drywall, so you could probably match thickness in one layer instead of having to build it up. Of course, if the thickness you need to build out exactly matches a sheet of drywall, then you've got all the options in the world!

#### Additional items of note:

- That insulation has a vapor barrier on it, but it's useless, since it's not contiguous and it's not all oriented correctly. I hope that it's simply being used for sound deadening on an interior wall. If not, you've got a really cold wall and the next point is critical...
- I'm assuming this is *not* a load bearing wall. If so, you've got a significant issue where the top plate is cut through for the pipe on the right-hand side.
- The pipe on the left-hand side appears to completely bypass the top plate, meaning that your furring will have to leave a gap to accommodate it. You'll probably want to use some steel protector plates (usually used to protect electrical wiring in the wall) to protect the pipe so you don't accidentally try to run a screw through the cabinet and directly into your water supply line.
- Do note [JACK's recommendation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/197540/34147) to also do something about the cable conduit run, as well.

And now you know why the previous person left this part of the wall unfinished... It's unprofessional, it looks bad, and it's going to take *work* to do it right.

Comment: You'd think the guy who spell-checks _everyone else's_ posts would spell check his own. :/ Thanks isherwood...

Answer (score 0):

Repairing the wall first is the correct way to go about this. You will have to rework that BX cable and what appears to be a copper water line.